# Swift CLI - $PATH is incomplete

Tags: swift, command-line-interface

I'm building a CLI tool as a Swift Package. Part of the process requires me to invoke some processes (such as `gsutil`). When I try to invoke those, I always end up with
`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'launch path not accessible'`

Some further analysis revealed that regular commands suchs as `pwd` or `which` work just fine. As pictured below, if I try to `echo $PATH`, I get an incomplete result.

[image: debugging]
The value of `$PATH` while running the project directly

`/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin\n`

is completely different from my actual `$PATH` variable:

```sh
echo $PATH
/Users/skwiggs/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/skwiggs/.npm-global/bin:/Users/skwiggs/.rbenv/bin:/Users/skwiggs/.rbenv/shims:/Users/skwiggs/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/skwiggs/.npm-global/bin:/Users/skwiggs/.rbenv/bin:/Users/skwiggs/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
```

How can I ensure that my env variables are correctly set while debugging my CLI tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the tool directly from a shell will pass it the expected `$PATH` value, so this issue only happens when debugging.

If you want to debug your program with the correct `$PATH` value, you can add an Environment Variable in the active scheme. That variable is only used while debugging, so it's safe to override it (it will be ignored when invoking your product from a shell).

1. Open a terminal
2. Run `echo $PATH`
3. Copy the output

Then, open XCode

Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Environment Variables -> Add.

**Name** `PATH` **Value** `<paste the value from terminal>`

[image: scheme environment variable]

Build & run, you can now debug as if your project was invoked from a shell.

(keep in mind you'll have to do this for every new project where this behaviour is needed, and any change to your `$PATH` will have to be retrofitted to your projects)

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Swift, you can access your environment variables directly using

```swift
guard let path = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["PATH"] else {
    return
}
// ...
```

Comment: It's not so much that I need to access `PATH` directly, I rely on it being complete so that I can invoke shell commands like I would in the terminal :/